# How to replace invoice number sequence in Odoo 8 by the invoice id

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to replace the invoice number sequence by the invoice id from the database but I don't have this option in from ODOO interface so I am sure I need to create a module for that or something but I have  no idea how to solve this , any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the sequences from the user interface, but it is hidden, so you must [Activate Developer Mode](http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/odoo/usage/debug-mode.html#id2).

1. Go to **Settings > Technical > Sequences & Identifiers > Sequences**
2. Find the *Customer Invoices* Sequence

However, I don't believe that you will have the option to use the ID as the sequence. This may be somewhat intentional as it's not typically a great idea to expose database IDs directly. So in your case, it may be necessary to write a module to change this behavior if you really need it for some reason.